# iOS Timeout for Incorrect Passcode

Tags: ios, swift, security

Within the app I am working on I let the user use a passcode as a backup for their TouchID. Obviously for security reasons this passcode should have some form of 'timeout' akin to the iPhone lock screen.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

My initial thoughts are saving the users last incorrect attempt and doing a check to see if its more than x amount of minutes before the current date.

I think this would work in practice however tying it to the system clock is most definitely not the most secure way.

Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented some form of this in several apps. What I typically do is use a timer that begins when the user interacts with the app (and also cancels the previous timer if one exists). When the time runs out, then the timeout method is run.

Something Like this:

```
- (void)pressedButton:(UIButton *)button {
  // record button press

  [self scheduleInteractionTimer];
}

- (void)scheduleInteractionTimer {
  if (_timeoutTimer) {
    [_timeoutTimer invalidate];
  }
  _timeoutTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:timeoutTime target:self selector:@selector(timeoutTripped) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
  _timeoutTimer.tolerance = 5.0; // optional
  [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:_timeoutTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}

- (void)timeoutTripped {
  // whatever should be done for a timeout...
}
```

You could definitely tie -scheduleInteractionTimer to an incorrect response or anything else that you'd like.

edit: I would also recommend dismissing the passcode view when the app enters the background.

Cheers

Anthony